# Insert query not working in MySQL , PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is my code to insert data in MySQL as Back-end and PHP as front-end
Connection is established properly but insert query is not working neither it is showing any error as per the else conditions at the end after insert query
It is not reaching inside the $_POST['submit'] too.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>
<body>
    <form type="post" name="addimage" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
     Album Name<input type="text" name="albumname">
    <input type="file" name="filesToUpload" id="filesToUpload" multiple=""/>
    </p>
       Client Name<input type="text" name="clientname">
       <br>Location<input type="text" name="location">
        <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</body>
</form>
</html>
<?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "apostrophe";
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","apostrophe");
 mysqli_select_db($con,"apostrophe");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
echo "reached";
$albumname=$_REQUEST['albumname'];
$images=$_REQUEST['filesToUpload'];
$client=$_REQUEST['clientname'];
$loc=$_REQUEST['loc'];
echo "reached submit";
$sql="INSERT INTO album(albumname,images,clientname,location)VALUES('$albumname','$albumname','$client','$loc')";
echo "reached down";
if($con->query($sql)===TRUE)
{
 echo "Success";
}
else
echo "Failed";
}
?>
```

Comment: you don't need this `mysqli_select_db($con,"apostrophe");` you already declared all 4 parameters above that. Plus, your `echo "Failed";` doesn't help you. get the real error and use error reporting.

Comment: Is this the way to store file `file` ??

Comment: plus, it's failing for another reason and error reporting would have told you about it. You're also using `'$albumname','$albumname'` twice; *why?*. You also are not moving that file, so this tells me that you're trying to enter binary data.

Comment: image will not be inserted either.

Comment: i am jus doing trial and error,
I am using $albumname 2 times just because i want to do file passing , that pasrt is working well, wanted to check if there is any error other than that.
I don't want to insert any image rightnow, just want to insert the data initially

Comment: it should be noted that your code is very vulnerable to SQL-injections.

Answer (score 2):

The original code has quite a few errors in ( the form straddles the `body`, wrong declaration for form method, title outside the head etc ) and there is no attempt at handling the actual uploaded images. Hopefully the following ought to give you a headstart with getting the file handling piece completed - though no doubt I have missed something too '-)

```
<?php
    $status='';
    /* Might as well test that all necessary fields are included in form submission */
    if( isset( $_POST['submit'], $_POST['albumname'], $_POST['clientname'], $_POST['location'] ) ){

        /* only need to declare the db connection if the variables are set */
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "apostrophe";

        /* create the db conn */
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","apostrophe");

        /* at least some basic filtering if you intend to place user submitted content directly in the sql */
        $albumname=strip_tags( filter_input( INPUT_POST,'albumname',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );
        $client=strip_tags( filter_input( INPUT_POST,'clientname',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) ); 
        $loc=strip_tags( filter_input( INPUT_POST,'location',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );



        /* handle file uploads */
        $fieldname='filesToUpload';

        foreach( $_FILES[$fieldname]['name'] as $i => $name ) {
            if( !empty( $_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'][$i] ) ) {

                $filename = $_FILES[$fieldname]['name'][$i];
                $size = $_FILES[$fieldname]['size'][$i];
                $type = $_FILES[$fieldname]['type'][$i];
                $tmpfile  = $_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'][$i];

                /* copy file to final destination - this is not complete!! */
                $bytes=move_uploaded_file( $tmpfile, '/path/to/final/directory/'.$filename );

                /* to debug uncomment below */
                #echo $filename,$tmpfile,$size,$type;
            }
        }

        /* prepare and execute sql */
        $sql="INSERT INTO `album` ( `albumname`, `images`, `clientname`, `location` ) VALUES ( '$albumname', '$albumname', '$client', '$loc' )";

        /* set status variable to be displayed under form */
        $status=( $con->query( $sql )===TRUE ) ?  "Success" : "Failed";

    } else {
        $status='bad foo';
        $status=print_r( $_POST, true );
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>File upload and database inserts</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" name="addimage" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            Album Name<input type="text" name="albumname">
            <input type="file" name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" multiple=""/>

            Client Name<input type="text" name="clientname">
            <br>
            Location<input type="text" name="location">
            <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </form><?php echo $status; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"though no doubt I have missed something too"* - Yep `$_POST['loc']` => `name="location"` - Plus, it's hard to say if the OP wants to send the file(s) to a folder or as a BLOB/LONGBLOB. Good luck Ram ;-) oh and `'$albumname', '$albumname'` is used twice. No idea again for that.

Comment: :) thanks @Fred-ii- ~ good spot by the way, I didn't notice that mistook. I figured the use of `$albumname` twice in the sql was because the OP didn't know how to get the filename - but as they say `"To assume is to make an ass of u and me"`

Comment: welcome. I made a slight edit where `$_POST['loc']` had to read as `$_POST['location']` ;-) you missed it.

Comment: "bad foo" is the output
Can i know where should i edit the code ,
Tried to understand yours and its far better than what I used.
Thanks a ton,
But please help me with this "Bad Foo"
@RamRaider

Comment: added in a small amendment ( `print_r($_POST)` ) which should help identify which fields exist in your POST array - compare that to the names in the form to se if there are differences.

Comment: I think it is the reference to the file field - this will be available in the `$_FILES` array - so remove `$_POST['filesToUpload']` from the `isset` test!

Answer (score 0):

Change your line :
     `<form type="post" name="addimage" enctype="multipart/form-data">`
to
     `<form method="post" name="addimage" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Indeed a good catch but you missed a few things. See my last comment under their question. That should give you a clue. I decided not to post an answer for this one. Too many unknowns for my taste.

Comment: I know but first mistake is method. I think that after this he can solve his problem

Comment: *"I think that after this he can solve his problem"* - That isn't what posting an answer is about. You only posted a typo fix.